# highlight active menu item on Page Scroll?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to add a active function to the current menu item on page scroll. It’s a single page with different sections. When click on an item, the active state should switch to the current one.

As you scroll down the page, the active menu item changes. How is this done? Would guys give me a answer base on my demo coding? Thanks.

My demo: http://jsfiddle.net/x2skzp1p/1/

```js
  var menuContainer = $('header').height();

  function scrollToAnchor(anchorName) {
    var aTag = $("div[name='" + anchorName + "']");
    $('html,body').animate({
      scrollTop: aTag.offset().top - menuContainer
    }, 'slow');
    console.log(anchorName);
  }
```

```css
.fluid {
  clear: both;
  margin-left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  display: block;
}
/* Mobile Layout: 480px and below. */

body {
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
  font-family: "Open Sans", Helvetica, "Heiti TC", "Microsoft JhengHei", "Microsoft Yahei", "PMingLiU", sans-serif;
  font-size: 100%;
  margin-top: 0px;
}
.gridContainer {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding-left: 1.1375%;
  padding-right: 1.1375%;
  clear: none;
  float: none;
  width: auto;
}
#header {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #FF6600;
}
/* header - navigation */

#subnav {
  height: 100%;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #1BBC9B;
  font-size: 120%;
}
#navmenu ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: 4px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: 0%;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  width: 650px;
}
#navmenu li {
  display: inline;
  float: left;
}
#navmenu a {
  color: #294C52;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
}
#navmenu li a {
  border-right: 1px solid #294C52;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}
#navmenu li:last-child a {
  border-right: 1px solid #576979;
  /* no border on last list item */
}
#navmenu li:first-child a {
  background-color: #294C52;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
#navmenu a:hover,
nav a:active {
  background-color: #1BBC9B;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
#content {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1000px;
  height: 100%;
  margin-top: 1px;
}
#section1 {
  background-color: #294C52;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  margin-top: 198px;
}
#section2 {
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
}
#section3 {
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
}
#section4 {
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
  margin-left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}
#content-about-org-left {
  width: 48.1012%;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  float: left;
  clear: none;
}
#content-about-org-centre {
  width: 48.1012%;
  margin-left: 1.2658%;
  clear: none;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  float: right;
}
#content-about-org-right {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
#section5 {
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
}
/* content - typography */

.content-list {
  list-style-type: none;
  color: #294C52;
  text-indent: -25px;
  font-size: 100%;
  line-height: 173%;
}
.content-list-bold {
  font-weight: bolder;
  font-size: 110%;
  color: #294C52;
}
.content-title {
  background-color: #903233;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  padding-top: 3px;
}
.content-p-white {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  text-align: justify;
  line-height: 25px;
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
}
.content-p-black {
  color: #294C52;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  text-align: justify;
  line-height: 25px;
  font-size: 100%;
}
.content-p-black-b {
  color: #294C52;
  font-weight: bolder;
  padding-left: 10px;
  font-size: 110%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="gridContainer clearfix">
  <header id="header">
    <nav id="subnav" class="fluid">
      <ul id="navmenu">
        <li><a onClick="scrollToAnchor('section1');" title="成立背景">SECTION 1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a onClick="scrollToAnchor('section2');" title="協會使命">SECTION 2</a>
        </li>
        <li><a onClick="scrollToAnchor('section3');" title="營運模式">SECTION 3</a>
        </li>
        <li><a onClick="scrollToAnchor('section4');" title="協會組織">SECTION 4</a>
        </li>
        <li><a onClick="scrollToAnchor('section5');" title="活動及刊物">SECTION 5</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <!--end of header-->
  <!--start of content-->
  <div class="fluid" id="content">
    <div id="section1" class="fluid" name="section1">
      <p class="content-p-white">《2013年香港殘疾人士貧窮情況報告》顯示介乎18至64歲適齡工作的殘疾人士的貧窮率為22.4%，遠較相同年齡群的整體貧窮率10.5%為高。再者，按經濟活動身分劃分，近18萬名的殘疾適齡工作人士當中，只有39.1%有從事經濟活動，遠低於整體人口中同年齡層的72.8%。</p>
      <p class="content-p-white">於2013年3月初，一群熱心人士包括郭鍵勳博士、謝俊謙教授及伍杏修先生等有意建立一個各方協作平台，改善殘疾人士的就業困難。</p>
      <p class="content-p-white">資訊科技易達協會有限公司 Accessible IT Development Association Limited (AIDA) 於2014年11月正式註冊成立。</p>
      <!--<div id="secttion1-bg"></div>--></div>
    <!--end of section1-->
    <div id="section2" class="fluid" name="section2">
      <article>
        <h2 class="content-title">&nbsp;&nbsp;SECTION 2</h2>

        <p class="content-p-black">資訊科技易達協會是一個社會企業致力提供專業資訊科技服務，同時為嚴重殘疾人士提供培訓及工作機會，讓學員可選擇在家居從事資訊科技相關工作；協會全力推動無障礙軟件開發，協助社會資訊共融。</p>
      </article>
    </div>
    <!--end of section2-->
    <div id="section3" class="fluid" name="section3">
      <article>
        <h2 class="content-title">&nbsp;&nbsp;SECTION 3</h2>

        <figure>
          <img src="images/2-about-us_03.jpg" alt="營運模式示意圖" class="alignRight" title="營運模式示意圖" />
        </figure>
        <p class="content-p-black">全面利用現代通訊科技的便利，解決殘疾人士面對指定工作地點的限制，讓他們可選擇在家居或院舍工作，同時得到必要的護理。AIDA選擇網頁開發作為起步點，由「無障礙學堂」(Barrier-Free School) 及業界專業義工負責培訓學員，讓他們掌握指定技術。</p>
        <p class="content-p-black">AIDA會承接工作項目，將項目分拆，然後將組件分配給技術程度不同的學員，並會密切督導整個項目的進行。AIDA已經與本地多間知名網頁開發公司結為合作伙伴，致力確保AIDA的所有服務均符合市場要求。AIDA會以殘疾友善機構的工作項目作為開始，當累積一定成功往績後，會推廣至主流市場。</p>
      </article>
    </div>
    <!--end of section3-->
    <div id="section4" class="fluid" name="section4">
      <article>
        <h2 class="content-title">&nbsp;&nbsp;SECTION 4</h2>

        <div id="content-about-org-left" class="fluid">
          <ul class="content-list">
            <li class="content-list-bold">名譽贊助人</li>
            <li>謝俊謙教授</li>
            <li class="content-list-bold">主席</li>
            <li>郭鍵勳博士</li>
            <li class="content-list-bold">副主席</li>
            <li>劉海軍先生</li>
            <li class="content-list-bold">義務秘書</li>
            <li>伍杏修先生</li>
            <li class="content-list-bold">義務司庫</li>
            <li>郭皓君女士</li>
            <li class="content-list-bold">核數師</li>
            <li></li>
            <li class="content-list-bold">義務法律顧問</li>
            <li>林子絪女士</li>
            <li class="content-list-bold">義務總幹事</li>
            <li>蘇炳坤先生</li>
            <li class="content-list-bold">諮詢委員及指導</li>
            <li></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="content-about-org-centre" class="fluid">
          <ul class="content-list">
            <li class="content-list-bold">董事</li>
            <li>張健輝先生</li>
            <li>郭鍵勳博士</li>
            <li>郭皓君女士</li>
            <li>劉海軍先生</li>
            <li>羅偉祥先生</li>
            <li>伍杏修先生</li>
            <li>吳家榮博士</li>
            <li>蘇炳坤先生</li>
            <li>謝俊謙教授</li>
            <li>黃婉冰女士</li>
            <li>游寶榮先生</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="content-about-org-right" class="fluid">
          <ul class="content-list">
            <li class="content-list-bold">工作團隊</li>
            <li>王乃東 王迪清 江啟暉 利詠然 李俊輝</li>
            <li>李豪飛 冼永健 何浚彥 施嶸傑 翁文菁</li>
            <li>茹文祥 郭寧 章世恒 曾志豪 曾鈴茵</li>
            <li>黃新陽 蔡冀逵 鄭建慧 盧兆豐</li>
          </ul>
          <p>
            <img src="images/2-about-us_06.jpg" alt="工作團隊成員相片" title="工作團隊成員相片" />
          </p>
        </div>
      </article>
    </div>
    <!--end of section4-->
    <div id="section5" class="fluid" name="section5">
      <article>
        <h2 class="content-title">&nbsp;&nbsp;SECTION 5</h2>

        <ul class="content-list">
          <li class="content-list-bold">新春團拜</li>
          <li>日期︰2015年3月14日(星期六)</li>
          <li>地點︰金鐘添馬公園添馬茶座愛烘焙餐廳</li>
          <li>時間︰下午4:00- 5:30</li>
        </ul>
        <hr>
        <ul class="content-list">
          <li class="content-list-bold">第一次周年大會</li>
          <li>日期︰2015年3月14日(星期六)</li>
          <li>地點︰金鐘添馬公園添馬茶座愛烘焙餐廳</li>
          <li>時間︰下午3:30- 4:00</li>
        </ul>
        <hr>
        <ul class="content-list">
          <li class="content-list-bold">協會發展成長分享會</li>
          <li>日期︰2015年2月3日(星期二)</li>
          <li>地點︰金鐘添馬公園添馬茶座愛烘焙餐廳</li>
          <li>時間︰上午11:00- 下午4:00</li>
          <li>內容：</li>
          <li>1. Delifrance午膳</li>
          <li>2. 匯報協會最新發展，就大家感興趣的事務進行商討</li>
          <li>3. IT人Ben Wong 個人經歷分享</li>
          <li>4. 參觀香港大學校園或自由活動</li>
        </ul>
        <hr>
        <ul class="content-list">
          <li class="content-list-bold">協會發展成長分享會</li>
          <li>日期︰2015年2月3日(星期二)</li>
          <li>地點︰金鐘添馬公園添馬茶座愛烘焙餐廳</li>
          <li>時間︰上午11:00- 下午4:00</li>
          <li>內容：</li>
          <li>1. Delifrance午膳</li>
          <li>2. 匯報協會最新發展，就大家感興趣的事務進行商討</li>
          <li>3. IT人Ben Wong 個人經歷分享</li>
          <li>4. 參觀香港大學校園或自由活動</li>
        </ul>
        <hr>
      </article>
    </div>
    <!--end of section5-->
  </div>
  <!--end of content-->
</div>
<!--end of gridContainer-->
```

Comment: you should add <a href="#section4" onClick="scrollToAnchor('section1');" title="成立背景">section4</a> like this

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready( function (){
var topMenu = $("#navmenu"),
topMenuHeight = topMenu.outerHeight()+15,
// All list items
menuItems = topMenu.find("a"),
// Anchors corresponding to menu items
scrollItems = menuItems.map(function(){
  var item = $($(this).attr("href"));
  if (item.length) { return item; }
  });
 });
```

// Bind to scroll

```
      $(window).scroll(function(){
   // Get container scroll position
   var fromTop = $(this).scrollTop()+topMenuHeight;

   // Get id of current scroll item
var cur = scrollItems.map(function(){
 if ($(this).offset().top < fromTop)
   return this;
});
 // Get the id of the current element
  cur = cur[cur.length-1];
  var id = cur && cur.length ? cur[0].id : "";
  // Set/remove active class
  menuItems.parent().removeClass("active")
 .end().filter("[href=#"+id+"]").parent().addClass("active");
});

            <header id="header">    
          <nav id="subnav" class="fluid">
          <ul id="navmenu">
            <li><a href="#section1" onClick="scrollToAnchor('section1');" title="成立背景">SECTION 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#section2" onClick="scrollToAnchor('section2');" title="協會使命">SECTION 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#section3" onClick="scrollToAnchor('section3');" title="營運模式">SECTION 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#section4" onClick="scrollToAnchor('section4');" title="協會組織">SECTION 4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#section5" onClick="scrollToAnchor('section5');" title="活動及刊物">SECTION 5</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </header>
```

and add this style

```
#navmenu li a .active {
 background-color: #294C52;
 color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Comment: i have added your code but it may be some mistakes.
http://jsfiddle.net/x2skzp1p/17

Answer (score 0):

You can use `onscroll` event to set active div and an `active` class to set it:

```
$(function () {

    $("body").onscroll(function () {
        $("#navmenu li").removeClass("active");
        if ($("body").scrollTop() > $("#section5").offset().top)
            $("#navmenu li").eq(4).addClass("active");
        else if ($("body").scrollTop() > $("#section4").offset().top)
            $("#navmenu li").eq(3).addClass("active");
        else if ($("body").scrollTop() > $("#section3").offset().top)
            $("#navmenu li").eq(2).addClass("active");
        else if ($("body").scrollTop() > $("#section2").offset().top)
            $("#navmenu li").eq(1).addClass("active");
        else
            $("#navmenu li").eq(0).addClass("active");
    });
});
```